# Plotting a "regression line" with confidence interval for multiple regression, keeping other covariate(s) fixed

Tags: r, linear-regression, visualization, lm, ggplot2

Suppose I have a dataset with outcome y, and covariates x and z, for example:

```r
N = 100
x = rnorm(N)
z = rnorm(N)
y = 3*x + 2*z + rnorm(N)
dataset = data.frame(x=x, z=z, y=y)
```

For a univariate regression of y on x, I can obtain a plot with confidence interval, as follows:

```r
ggplot(dataset) + 
   geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
   stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~x)
```

[image]

**QUESTION: How could I get the same plot for a multivariate regression of y on x and z, where the line corresponds to a specific value of z (say, z=0.42)?**

I can draw the line as follows:

```r
model <- lm(data=dataset, formula = y~x+z)

special_z = 0.42

ggplot() + 
   geom_point(data=dataset, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
   geom_abline(
      slope = coef(model)["x"], 
      intercept = coef(model)["(Intercept)"] + special_z*coef(model)["z"],
      color = "blue")
```

[image]

However, how could I add the accompanying confidence interval to this line?

Comment: Using the `emmeans` or `ggeffects` packages to compute the predicted values and CIs you need might be the easiest way to get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `marginaleffects` package can do this (and a lot more). See the vignette on plots: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/plot.html

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(marginaleffects)

N = 100
x = rnorm(N)
z = rnorm(N)
y = 3*x + 2*z + rnorm(N)
dataset = data.frame(x=x, z=z, y=y)

model <- lm(data=dataset, formula = y~x+z)

plot_predictions(model, condition = list("x", "z" = 0.42))
```

[image]

```r
plot_predictions(model,
    condition = list("x", "z" = "threenum"),
    points = .3,
    rug = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
plot_predictions(model, condition = list("x", "z" = stats::fivenum)) + 
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_brewer("Dark2") +
    scale_color_brewer("Dark2")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `visreg` r package, look here for more details [visreg](https://pbreheny.github.io/visreg/index.html)

```
simple_model <- lm(data=dataset, formula = y~x+z)
visreg(simple_model, "x")
```

[image: model1]

for models with an interaction term,The visreg package offers two methods to visualize the effect of two explanatory variables here one of them.

```
int_model <- lm(data=dataset, formula = y~x*z)
visreg(int_model, "x",by="z",overlay=TRUE)
```

[image]